# closed form of f(n,k) = f(n-1,k-1) + f(n-1,k) + f(n-2,k-1)

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I am stuck at solving linear recurrence relation of 2 variables :

```
f(n,k) = f(n-1,k-1) + f(n-1,k) + f(n-2,k-1)
```

what would be closed form for f(n,k)?

Base condition :
 f(1,1) = 2 , 
                 f(2,1) = 4 ,  f(2,2) = 2
 & 
 f(x,0) = 1 { x is a whole number } ,
 also f(n,k) = 0 if k>n or k<0 or n<0

Comment: You need more base conditions to solve this. For example, $f(1,2) = f(0,1) + f(0,2) + f(-1,1)$ and your base conditions say nothing about what any of these are. Also, where are you stuck? What methods do you know of for solving linear recurrences in 2 variables? Where did you see this problem?

Comment: See [the advice here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). Low-context questions are not a good fit for this site and may be put "on-hold". See [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: okay here are some more base cases : f(1,1) = 2, f(2,1) = 4 , f(2,2) = 2. But I think these can be derived from already given base cases. we only have to take f(n,k) = 0 if n or k are -ve

Comment: The generating function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty f(n,k) x^n y^k$ would almost certainly be some rational function with a denominator of $1-xy-x-x^2 y$.  Unfortunately, it appears that this denominator is an irreducible polynomial (if Wolfram Alpha's failure to be able to factor is any indication)...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that f(n,k) = 0 if k > n  , also I observed that f(n,k) = 2 when n = k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in the given recurrence
$$
f(n,k) = f(n - 1,k - 1) + f(n - 1,k) + f(n - 2,k - 1)
$$
we put 
$$
f(n,k) = D(n - k,k)
$$
then we get
$$
D(n - k,k) = D(n - k,k - 1) + D(n - k - 1,k) + D(n - k - 1,k - 1)
$$
i.e.
$$
D(n,k) = D(n,k - 1) + D(n - 1,k) + D(n - 1,k - 1)
$$
and this is the recurrence relation defining [the Delannoy Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number)

Therefore putting

and since
$$
D(n,k) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{\min (n,k)} {  \binom{n+k-j}{n} \binom{n}{j}  } 
  = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{\min (n,k)} {2^{\,j}  \binom{n}{j} \binom{k}{j} } 
$$
whose derivation is well exposed in the link above, then
$$
f(n,k) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{\min (n - k,k)} {  \binom{n-j}{n-k} \binom{n-k}{j}  }
 = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{\min (n - k,k)} {2^{\,j}    \binom{n-k}{n-k-j} \binom{k}{k-j}  }
$$

Other interesting properties and relations are provided in [OEIS sequence A008288](http://oeis.org/A008288).

With the "standard" initial conditions given above the $f(n,k)$ triangle starts as

[image: Delannoy_N_1]

If your initial conditions are different, then an appropriate combination and shifting
of the standard triangle shall be considered.

For instance, $f(n,k)+f(n-1,k-1)$ would give

[image: Delannoy_N_2]

which looks to match your initial conditions

Comment: I believe this is what I want, thanks for the help. But how to inject the initial conditions i.e. f(1,1) = 2 ?

Comment: I added the combination which looks to abide to the initial conditions you gave, including ( partially) the last in your new post.

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate your help very much. Actually I figured it out before you updated your answer , but anyway thanks :)

Comment: @AmbeshTiwari: good , that means that you master the subject now. I am pleased it helped.